# How to use paramiko to talk interactivity with a remote application?

Tags: python, stdio, paramiko

I am trying to use paramiko to interatively speak with an command line application, but I'm doing something wrong.

```
# that's the echo.py, the script I am connecting to via SSH
import sys, time
while 1:
    x = sys.stdin.readline()
    sys.stdout.write("got-" + x) # x already contains newline



# client.py
import paramiko

ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

ssh.connect('127.0.0.1', username='user', password='pass')

(stdin, stdout, stderr) = ssh.exec_command(r"python C:\test\echo.py")

stdin.write("xxx\n")
print "got back [%s]" % stdout.read()  # <<< here the code got stuck, getting nothing back
```

Note: the only case that worked for me was to have the `echo.py` quit and do `stdout.readlines()` on the client, but obviously this is not what I was looking for.

I need to be able to **send and receive messages by using stdin and stdout**, optionally with some kind of timeout support.

Comment: Is your problem just the missing "s" in `tdaout.read()` or that is just a typo in your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the problem is that when you run `sys.stdout.write` it writes to the STDOUT buffer, but the buffer is not flushed until done so manually or closed (stdout is a [File Object](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#file-objects), which you can confirm yourself with `type(sys.stdout)`). Since your loop is infinite, the buffer is never flushed.

Changing your loop in echo.py to this should do the trick:

```
while 1:
    x = sys.stdin.readline()
    sys.stdout.write("got-" + x) # x already contains newline
    sys.stdout.flush() # flush the buffer
```